# layer popup with jQuery

Tags: jquery, layer

I don't know what the name of the function is, but you can see it on http://twitter.com/ when you click on the link login in the top right. Then a layer appears where you can type your username and password. So I need an tutorial for creating this layer with jquery. Does anyone have a good source?

Comment: It's called a Lightbox or Modal Window. There a plenty of jQuery scripts out there for doing such a thing. I personally like facebox.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest approach is the "dialog" available from the  jQuery UI library.

http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Dialog

Comment: Can I say, that the dialog should openet, there where my link is. I mean when I click on a link, then the dialog should be opened there 5px undere the link.

Comment: Here an example by http://www.skyscanner.ie/ if you click on the link select from list above the box, where you type the airport. Is this a modal window too?

Comment: "modal" implies that the rest of the web page is unavailable (often grayed-out) while the dialog is open.  That one isn't modal.