# Change user avatar from avatar images available on my site?

Tags: php, html, css, image, selection

Please be kind, I know you guys are very intelligent, but not all everyone in this world is and I assume, some of you may not have been initially.

I don't have college, and I am self learner, so please be kind with my question and kindly help me out to solve this.

File 1 `weall.php`:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['route']) && $_GET['route'] === 'world') {
    include "world.php";
}

?>
```

File 2 `world.php`:

```
<form method="post" action="weall.php?route=world" >
 <input type="text" name="yourname" />
 <input type="text" name="avatar" />
 <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

I have certain avatar in my `/image/avatar` directory of web-root.

How can I pop-up browser, and let user select any avatar image of their choice and fill my "avatar, input" field.

Comment: you want to "pop-up", first define that!! do you want a file upload form to open or do you want a custom javascript pop up, second, do you want the avatar image file name in the field? or the actual file? take a look at your question, imagine your self in my position, and you can see that i have no clue what you are really asking, be specific? where is the code you have tried? how am i supposed to guess........

Comment: The simplest way to archive what you want, would be using a hidden div where all the selectable avatars. You could also make that div floating so that it looks like a popup, then you can use JQuery to select the images into your avatar field.

Comment: no file upload. Only popup my avatar directory , and user select that image, and boom! done :)

Comment: @Prix bro, i may have 100 avatar images, and adding that in hidden div, sounds crazy. My preference is currently popup->select->done->submit. Thanks :)

Comment: @JohnyBravo dude why would you add manually? [**all you need is to use your PHP to iterate on the directory**](http://php.net/manual/en/class.directoryiterator.php) and create the div and elements for you duh... The hidden div sounds the most rational to me it would prevent you from creating a popup which 70%+ of the internet blocks by default and would allow the user to preview each image without loading all images.

Comment: @Prix bro, you got a point for pop-up, but i have got jQuery solution for that, my main concern to load in hidden div is , page will keep on loading until all images are loaded, and if i don't load image, and just iterate files in directory, with your link, it would be hard to find which filename has what image for user. :(

Comment: @JohnyBravo nope, you can load the images in set only after he opens the div and as the users navigate on the div with JQuery and Ajax all you need is the list of images you have available which you can do in PHP then once he sees the first set if he doesn't like it he press an next arrow or next button. Once he clicks on a image you can easily use another JQuery to catch that action and give you the image `src` inside a hidden field called avatar or even show a OK button to confirm the change and process that.

Comment: wow.I think i got an idea or may be the this is what you are trying to say. I will place a link to avatar directory as button inside my div, and once he clicks that `link#button`, i will iterate the next directory via ajax and will load image accordingly. Cool, let me see how this goes. Thanks :)

Comment: [You don't really need a link see.](http://api.jquery.com/show/) I think you don't even need the AJAX, you can do it all with just JQuery. Once the user opens that page you use your PHP grab all the images you have on the directory then you can use JQuery show to initially display the div and once the div is displayed you also insert the HTML with the initial set of images, then you just change the HTML with the other images once the user click on the next or previous image/button or whatever you choose and you won't even need AJAX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You probably would need to use AJAX **,** JQuery

- You would need to have an Avatar button **(** To select/Change Avatar **)**
- You would need a div to show the Avatars **(** This will be empty until user clicks above button **)**
- When user clicks Avatar button you would retrieve partial list of Avatars **(** using AJAX **)** and would display in the Avatars div **.** You would need to provide ability to show more Avatars if user likes to browse more

And then for the actual selection of an Avatar **,** you could use a simple radio button style or you could go for a flashy javascript based plugins **,** etc which is up to you **. . .**

> If you want that div to be a pop up style , these links might help **:**

[Show a div as a modal pop up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6263303/show-a-div-as-a-modal-pop-up)

[layer popup with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5071579/layer-popup-with-jquery)

Or altogether you could use a Pop Up window .
 In any case you probably would need to update the parent window with the Avatar selected in the pop up .

Answer (score 1):

It's not that several lines of code can complete what you want. You might want to search a bit for image picker. So far I can see a good one is this image picker plugin: http://rvera.github.io/image-picker/

Comment: no you got me wrong, bro, It should not display all avatar image already. I have default image option when there is no avatar added. So, its like popup->select->done->submit. Thanks

Comment: I see. basic idea is you can: 1. fetch all the files from that directory. 2. use any popup js plugin (fancybox, lightbox) to display the images in the popup. 3. bind click event to those images, from which will trigger fill input field.